# Require authentication for IRC connections (InspIRCd)

Tags: irc, instant-messaging, inspircd

We're trying to move our team chat from Skype to a private IRC server (InspIRCd) and we need to require some sort of authentication to prevent public access. I know we could have a global server password but that doesn't allow us to control *who* has access and obviously doesn't scale well (team member leaves, etc).

Are there any modules for Inspircd which support multi-user authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The included [sqlauth module](http://wiki.inspircd.org/Modules/2.0/sqlauth) seems like exactly what you want here.

Answer (score 7):

The [sqlauth module](http://wiki.inspircd.org/Modules/2.0/sqlauth) as devicenull suggested allows you to store usernames and password hashes in a SQL database (SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc) and can even integrate with the user table from an existing application ([mediawiki, phpBB, etc](https://wiki.inspircd.org/Integrating_m_sqlauth.so_with_other_software)).

The [ldapauth module](http://www.evanhoffman.com/evan/2010/10/28/setting-up-inspircd-as-an-internal-irc-server-for-companywide-chat/) supports directly integrating with LDAP servers (Active Directory, OpenLDAP, etc).

Another option is to have users connect through [ZNC](http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC) and not allow direct  access to InspIRCd at all. In addition to requiring authentication before a user can connect, ZNC also supports SSL and implements history buffers so users can stay in a channel persistently without actually being connected 24/7. When user reconnect they get a replay of all activity which occurred while they were gone.  ZNC supports simple password authentication out of the box, but ZNC modules also exist for using [SSL Client Certificates](http://wiki.znc.in/Certauth) or [external SASL authentication](http://wiki.znc.in/Cyrusauth) including [LDAP servers](http://markcunninghamblog.blogspot.com/2013/01/znc-auth-with-pamldap.html).

Comment: If I show up to a party four years late, the least I can do is bring cake.